# why 'HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found' occur when i refresh page through Browser in angular 2 latest version

Tags: angular

i have **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** error occur when i refresh page through Browser using angular 2 latest version.  How to solve this error?

Comment: check the request that happens in the browser network activity. is this the same request you expect?

Comment: What was the URL of the page? Could you post your component code related to that page?

Comment: it is localhost URL like 'http://localhost:59440/usersetup'

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've added a `base` to your `index.html`:

```
<base href="/">
```

If you did, it's probably something related to your hosting that you need to setup. It's hard to know without knowing where you're hosting your application, though.

For example, for Firebase Hosting, you could simply a configuration like this one:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Just see what are the rewrite rules for your hosting.